# How to access the value of a parameter from an Action<> called with a lambda expression in C# and store it in an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-recording, photon

I am working on an application developed with Unity 3D that uses the Photon Network and Photn voice libraries. I would like to receive the audio stream, store it in a stream, and later save it in a WAV file. From the Photon Voice Forums support, I was told to use:

```
PhotonVoiceNetwork.Client.OnAudioFrameAction += (playerId, voiceId, frame) => Debug.LogFormat("***** {0} {1} {2}", playerId, voiceId, frame[0]);
```

I can see the values of the received float frames printed on the logs, but I do not know how can I use that Action that they pointed out to access the float frame values. This is the original action declaration:

```
public Action<int, byte, float[]> OnAudioFrameAction { get; set; }
```

and I am thinking about to store the audio frames with something like this:

```
float[] samples;
        PhotonVoiceNetwork.Client.OnAudioFrameAction += (playerId, voiceId, frame) => samples = frame;

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        bw.Write(samples);
        bw.Flush();
        byte[] floatBytes = stream.ToArray();
```

The code above does not work, as in the line `bw.Write(samples);` the compiler says that the variable has not been initialized, which means that `PhotonVoiceNetwork.Client.OnAudioFrameAction += (playerId, voiceId, frame) => samples = frame;` is not assigning the received float value to the varible.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're already receiving the data in the third parameter of type `float[]`. What else do you need?

Comment: @dymanoid, I do not know how to access that value from the third parameter and save it in a stream, basically.

Comment: How would you consume the stream? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @dymanoid, what do you mean by "How would you consume the stream?"

Comment: We don't know how would you create your `Stream` instances and how would you use those instances in conjunction with the data retrieval using the event handler. Static methods? Instance methods? Anonymous methods? Once again, please post your code - how you think it all should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from your example that you want to store the *frame* parameter in the binary file, and then store the stream bytes in memory for future use.

You could declare data member `private byte[] m_floatBytes;` in your class, and register to the action like this:

```
PhotonVoiceNetwork.Client.OnAudioFrameAction += (playerId, voiceId, frame) => 
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        bw.Write(frame);
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        m_floatBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: @dymanoid While that would be good practice in general, `MemoryStream` (and also `BinaryWriter`) doesn't actually have any unmanaged resources, so it wouldn't actually cause any problems.

Comment: Thanks @dymanoid , I was in a rush to answer the targeted concern and neglected good code practices. Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Servy, a fair point, I thought the `BinaryWriter` has a finalizer, but in fact it doesn't. @JonVol, the `BinaryWriter` is `IDisposable` too, by the way.

Comment: @dymanoid, the `Close()` method of `BinaryWriter` calls `Dispose(true)`

Comment: @JonVol Which only ever disposes of the wrapped stream, if it was in fact configured to do so (which it should not be here), but the wrapped stream doesn't need to be disposed, and is also being disposed explicitly anyway, even though it doesn't do anything when it's disposed.  Disposing of it a second time is no more helpful than disposing of it the first time.